# Swift 5/Objective-C Expected Type parsing issue QMImageView

Tags: objective-c

I just upgraded this application to swift 5 and am getting a parsing issue; expected type error. I tried importing the uikit and foundation but that didn't seem to resolve the issue. I'm still pretty new to swift so I'm not sure exactly what the error means.

```
//
//  QMImageView.h
//  QMChatViewController
//
//  Created by Andrey Ivanov on 27.06.14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Quickblox. All rights reserved.
//
 
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "QMImageLoader.h"
 
 
@protocol QMImageViewDelegate ;
 
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, QMImageViewType) {
    QMImageViewTypeNone,
    QMImageViewTypeCircle,
    QMImageViewTypeSquare
};
 
@interface QMImageView : UIImageView
/**
 Default QMUserImageViewType QMUserImageViewTypeNone
 */
@property (assign, nonatomic) QMImageViewType imageViewType;
@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer;
@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSURL *url;
 
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <QMImageViewDelegate> delegate;
 
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url;
 
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
            placeholder:(UIImage *)placehoder
                options:(SDWebImageOptions)options
               progress:(SDWebImageDownloaderProgressBlock)progress
         completedBlock:(SDExternalCompletionBlock)completedBlock;
 
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
                  title:(NSString *)title
         completedBlock:(SDExternalCompletionBlock)completedBlock;
 
- (UIImage *)originalImage;
 
@end
 
@protocol QMImageViewDelegate <NSObject>
 
- (void)imageViewDidTap:(QMImageView *)imageView;
 
@end
```

error

```
Expected a type QMImageView.h
```

[photo of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45Vh1.png)

Comment: Post the error and relevant code. Do not post screenshots.

Comment: The type it's actually complaining about is `SDExternalCompletionBlock`.  QMImageView.h is just the file where it detected the problem.  Apparently you're using a library called SDWebImage but you're not importing a header for it.  (Also, this isn't Swift!)

Comment: So, does your error go away if you import whatever header(s) SDWebImage provides?

Comment: Yeah, the error went away but now I'm receiving a new error; a Nullability Issue '_Nullable' cannot be applied to non-pointer type 'int'

Comment: Please post another topic with your new question.